# how can i make my Application MS EDGE compatible

Tags: java, testing, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I am currently using IE11 for my application.

My boss came up with the new requirement of making the application MS EDGE compatible.
I tried today by simply firing the URL on EDGE but it redirect me to IE and and opens the webpage for me on IE.

Can anyone please suggest how can i stop the redirection of URL from EDGE to IE, so that i can test the functioning in MS EDGE as well.

Will just changing the ***http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"*** do.

Comment: Does the answer below and the Enterprise mode site list help you to find the solution for the issue? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned whether you want to use the **MS Edge legacy** browser or **MS Edge Chromium** browser.

I assume that you want to use the **MS Edge Chromium** browser.

I understand that when you try to visit the site in the Edge browser and site get launched in the IE browser. something like below.

[image]

This can happen if you have configured the [Enterprise mode site list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/what-is-enterprise-mode) on your machine.

You can refer to the steps below to verify it.

1. Open Local group policy editor.
2. Browse to the location below.

> Computer configuration -> Administrative templates -> Windows components -> Internet Explorer

3. Find and double click on **Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list** policy.
4. Check whether this policy is enabled or not. If it is enabled then try to note the location of the file list and try to access the file.
5. Modify the parameters for that specific site to let it access in the Edge browser.

If the site is an intranet site then the below policy also can cause the same behavior.

1. Open Local group policy editor.
2. Browse to the location below.

> Computer configuration -> Administrative templates -> Windows components -> Internet Explorer

3. Find and double click on **Keep all intranet site in internet explorer** policy.
4. If this policy is enabled then for testing purposes try to set it disabled or not configured.

Similar kinds of policies is available for the MS Edge Chromium browser. You can also try to check it. whether they are configured or not.

References:

1. [Configure using the Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-use-the-enterprise-mode-ie-website-list-policy)
2. [Configure all intranet sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-all-intranet-sites)

If you are using the MS Edge legacy browser then try to check the set policies for it may help you to fix the issue.